# Rails send_data passes plain text path as file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I cant figure out what Im doing wrong here.  Im using Carrierwave to allow users to upload PDF files to AWS.  So far upload and record creation go off without a hitch and when browsing the S3 bucket Im able to download and read the file no problem.

The issue Im having is with the "send_data" function in my controller  The file download is being triggered, but instead of the PDF thats in AWS im getting a txt file(with PDF extension), that contains only the path to the file.

here is my code, hopefully more experienced eyes will spot my error.

```
send_data @document.file.url.to_s, :type => "application/pdf", :disposition => "attachment", :filename => @document.title.to_s
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at semantic for those methods:

```
send_data(data, options = {})
send_file(path, options = {})
```

For [`send_data()`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/DataStreaming/send_data) you should open and read the file, for [`send_file()`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_file) you can use just a path to file.

```
send_data(File.read(@document.file.url.to_s), type: "application/pdf", disposition:  "attachment", filename: @document.title.to_s)
```